# Simple question but I've stacked little bit

Tags: python, json, pandas, python-requests

Sorry for asking kind of simple question, but I've stacked little bit. There are 3 tasks:
a)Get Data from API (I did),
b) Parse response data and save the response to JSON file (I did, it looks like: `"{\n  \"Count\": 93,\n  \"Message\": \"Response returned successfully\",\n  \"SearchCriteria\": null,\n  \"Results\": [\n    {\n      \"Country\": \"UNITED STATES (USA)\" )......`
c) Transform saved JSON data to target JSON data in the format given below:

```
[
    {
        "Country":"UNITED STATES (USA)",
        "Mfr_CommonName":"Tesla",
        "Mfr_ID":955,
        "Mfr_Name":"TESLA, INC.",
        "IsPrimary":true,
        "Name":"Passenger Car"
    },
    {
        "Country":"UNITED STATES (USA)",
        "Mfr_CommonName":"Tesla",
        "Mfr_ID":955,
        "Mfr_Name":"TESLA, INC.",
        "IsPrimary":false,
        "Name":"Multipurpose Passenger Vehicle (MPV)"
    },
    {
```

So I've tried to use :

```
new_file=pd.read_json ('file.json')
pd.json_normalize(new_file)
```

but no lack..
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated..:))

Comment: So, what went wrong? What was in `new_file`? I'm not familiar with `pd.read_json()`.

Comment: Maybe worth reading this - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. I'm struggling to see exactly where your error is coming

Comment: Also - I take it the space after read_json is a typo here, if not remove that in the code!

Comment: @FrancisWebb: How can that be a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all! I've found a solution:

```
with open('dirty.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    dirty = json.load(f)

clear = []
for i in dirty['Results']:
    if len(i['VehicleTypes']) == 0:
        end = 1
    else:
        end = len(i['VehicleTypes'])
    for j in range(end):
        card = {}
        card['Country'] = i['Country']
        card['Mfr_CommonName'] = i['Mfr_CommonName']
        card['Mfr_ID'] = i['Mfr_ID']
        card['Mfr_Name'] = i['Mfr_Name']
        try:
            card['IsPrimary'] = i['VehicleTypes'][j]['IsPrimary']
            card['Name'] = i['VehicleTypes'][j]['Name']
        except (IndexError, KeyError):
            pass
        clear.append(card)
```